# v-select changes width depending on length of selected item

Tags: vuetify.js

I am using v-selects inside a flexbox, and I would like the v-selects's size to depend on the flexbox settings instead of changing depending on whether a long or short item is selected.

Is there a way to make the width independent of the selected item?

Comment: yea sure , can you provide your approach men because, when I am trying it seems good [here](https://codepen.io/nilesh9836/pen/RwxdZOd?editors=101)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I had a similar idea yesterday and found a solution. I posted it as an answer below.

Comment: that's sounds good

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I remembered that it didn't happen when I used a v-container, so I mimicked the css of a v-container but with a few changes to apply a different style.
Essentially, if the v-select has rather low width, you can't get around setting the width of the v-select manually if you want it to stay a certain size, which in the end is what v-col is effectively doing.
I wanted it to change depending on the parent's width so I used a percentage and subtracted the total flexbox gap (20px) divided by the number of items (2) in the parent, like this:

```
.v-select-class {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.